# d3.js. Stream chart shifts with different data sets. Why?

Tags: d3.js

Code available here http://jsfiddle.net/zeleniy/ea1uL7w9/

```
data = [47, 13, 61, 46, 26, 32, 6, 85, 1, 14, 86, 77, 13, 66, 0, 20, 11, 87, 5, 15];
data = [52, 33, 53, 45, 59, 45, 42, 50, 53, 50, 37, 45, 52, 50, 46, 48, 52, 56, 58, 59];
width = 300;
height = 100;

xScale = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([0, data.length])
    .range([0, width]);
yScale = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([d3.min(data), d3.max(data)])
    .range([0, height])

area = d3.svg.area()
    .interpolate("basis")
    .x(function(d, i) { return xScale(i); })
    .y0(function(d) { return yScale(-d / 2); })
    .y1(function(d) { return yScale(d / 2); });

svg = d3.select("#stream")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

svg.selectAll("path")
    .data([this.data])
    .enter()
    .append("path")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + (height / 2) + ")")
    .style("fill", "red")
    .attr("d", area);
```

With first data set chart drawn in the center of svg element, as i expect. But with second data set stream shifts to the top of svg element. And i can't understand why. So why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first array contains values close to 0 and it's opening up your range.  This line, then, is a fudge to shift the path into that open window:

```
.attr("transform", "translate(0," + (height / 2) + ")")
```

That said, you are setting up your scales in a confusing way (to me at least).  I think about my domain as the min/max of my (plotted) dataset, in your case `-max(d/2)` and `max(d/2)`.    Further, I also think about my y-scale going from bottom to top as it would in a normal plot.  With these changes, you don't need to artificially move anything:

```
var dataMax = d3.max(data);
yScale = d3.scale.linear()
  .domain([ -dataMax/2, dataMax/2 ]) // real min/max of plotted data
  .range([height, 0]) //<- bottom to top, although it still works without this change...
```

In this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/ea1uL7w9/1/), I left an axis overlayed for illustration.